# Apache mod rewrite rules

Tags: apache

We have a requirement to redirect the user to the mobile site or the normal website based on the user agent.

I am trying to write the below code in my http.conf file but it does not seem to be working. Can someone point out my mistake?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/shop/website ^/shop/mobile [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below (removed a spurious caret from the redirect target, as well as the explicity 302 code) works for me in an httpd.conf, though you'd need to change it if you were putting it in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/foo.txt /bar.txt [L,R]
```

(If you were putting it into a .htaccess file, you'd remove the directory specifications, since you'd be putting it in directory context:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule foo.txt bar.txt [L,R]
```

I believe you can remove the explicit 302 redirect code, since 302 is the default.

Comment: the original code worked for me. the browsers default agent was not detected by apache. i used a mobile simulator with the same code to keep it working. thanks for ur response!